# Change or disable the iPhone rotating animation when orientation changes

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uideviceorientation

How do I change or disable the rotating animation when screen orientation changes from landscape to portrait, or vice versa?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you dont want your view controllers to rotate just override the shouldAutoRotateToInterface view controller method to return false for whichever orientation you dont want to support...[Here is a reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:).

In the case that u just want to handle rotation some other way, you can return false in the above methods and register  for UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification like so

```
    NSNotificationCenter* nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
[nc addObserver:self
       selector:@selector(handleOrientationDidChange:)
           name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification
         object:nil];
```

Now when u get the notifications u can do whatever you want with it...

Comment: I think he still wants it to rotate but to use a different animation or not animate at all.

Comment: changed answer to reflect that

Answer (score 16):

Yes, it is possible to disable the animation, without breaking everything apart.

The following codes will disable the "black box" rotation animation, without messing with other animations or orientation code:

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation {
    [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:YES];
}


- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO];
  /* Your original orientation booleans*/
}
```

Place it in your UIViewController and all should be well. Same method can be applied to any undesired animation in iOS.

Best of luck with your project.

Comment: For iOS 6+ (and previous) compatibility, you can put [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO] in willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration: instead of shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:

Comment: Remember to call the super implementation if you override these. Specifically, the apple docs say that if you are overriding willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration: or didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation: that "Your implementation of this method must call super at some point during its execution."

Answer (score 1):

The answer by @Nils Munch above is find for < iOS7.  For iOS 7 or later you can use:

```
- (void) viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator {
    [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO];

    [coordinator notifyWhenInteractionEndsUsingBlock:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext> context) {
        [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:YES];
    }];

    [super viewWillTransitionToSize:size withTransitionCoordinator:coordinator];
}
```

Comment: Just retested in the debugger, running iOS 8.4 and it's definitely being called when I rotate the device.  For < iOS7 it won't call this though.