# Disable orientation change rotation animation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, animation, orientation

I need to disable the animation that plays when the orientation changes. Is this possible? If not, is it possible to speed it up?

Just to clarify, i don't want to stop the orientation change, just the animation. I want an instant orientation change.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change or disable the iPhone rotating animation when orientation changes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2737866/change-or-disable-the-iphone-rotating-animation-when-orientation-changes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I remember correctly (this is always the sort of thing I have to play around with for a moment to get right) `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` and `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` are both inside the animation block, while `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:` runs after the animation block.  I believe you would need to lay out your views in `willRotate` so they appear in the position in which they would appear after the rotation *had they not rotated* (if that makes sense).  This way the animation will animate them from their original (correct) layout to the new (rotated) layout in the opposite direction that the device rotates, creating the appearance of no animation.  Once the rotation is complete, you can lay out your views, without animation, in `didRotate`, giving the impression that they rotate instantly.

Clear as mud, no?

Comment: unfortunately this is deprecated on iOS 8+

Answer (score 50):

Yes, it is possible to disable the animation, without breaking everything apart.

The following codes will disable the "black box" rotation animation, without messing with other animations or orientation code:

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation {
    [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:YES];
}


- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO];
  /* Your original orientation booleans*/

    return TRUE;
}
```

Place it in your UIViewController and all should be well. Same method can be applied to any undesired animation in iOS.

Best of luck with your project.

---

For 2016, it appears `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` is not available to be overridden.  The following does seem to work, and cause no other harm.

```
// these DO SEEM TO WORK, 2016
override func willRotateToInterfaceOrientation(
        toInterfaceOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientation, duration:NSTimeInterval)
    {
    UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)
    super.willRotateToInterfaceOrientation(toInterfaceOrientation,duration:duration)
    }
override func didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation(
        fromInterfaceOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientation)
    {
    super.didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation(fromInterfaceOrientation)
    UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)
    }
```

**However!!** Indeed both these functions are deprecated.  `viewWillTransitionToSize` now takes care of both the "before" and "after".

```
override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size:CGSize,
       withTransitionCoordinator coordinator:UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator)
    {
    coordinator.animateAlongsideTransition(nil, completion:
        {_ in
        UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)
        })
    UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)
    super.viewWillTransitionToSize(size, withTransitionCoordinator: coordinator);
    }
```

Comment: @teedayf No problem. Its useful in many places where you want the default animations gone.

Comment: Didn't work for me either... but adding it to willRotateToInterfaceOrientation did work.

Comment: @Lawson - FWIW, those are now deprecated.  See edit!

Comment: unfortunately this is deprecated on iOS 8+

Comment: any solution for swiftui ?

Answer (score 13):

In iOS8 you can disable rotation animations by disabling CALayer animations in your view controller's implementation of  `viewWillTransitionToSize`.

The inverse rotation mentioned in the accepted answer is useful if you want to *customize* the transition (see WWDC 2014 'View Controller Advancements in iOS 8') but not if you just want to prevent animation.

(N.B. Implementing `viewWillTransitionToSize` will prevent the deprecated pre-iOS8 rotation APIs from being called.)

```
- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator
{
    [super viewWillTransitionToSize:size withTransitionCoordinator:coordinator];
    [CATransaction begin];
    [CATransaction setDisableActions:YES];
    [coordinator animateAlongsideTransition:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext> context) {
        // You could make a call to update constraints based on the
        // new orientation here.
    } completion:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext> context) {
        [CATransaction commit];
    }];
}
```

Comment: this works strangely only for iPhone, on iPad the screen rotation is system animated :(

Comment: It disable any animation, It isn't useful.

Answer (score 5):

Based on Nils Munch's Answer, this is the Swift 3 version:

```swift
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: nil) { (_) in
        UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)
    }
    UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)
    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you re-layout your views when the view is about to be rotated I think when it really rotates it won't have animations.
I mean, write a method with the new coordinates, frames, positions for each subview and call that method in `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` or `willAnimateFirstHalfOfRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` 
(This is not a smart way of doing things though. I wonder, why do you need no-animation?)

Comment: I'm manually changing orientation in a modal view controller. When i dismiss the modal view controller i want the orientation to have already changed.

Comment: Then you can try to set your parent controller not to rotate just before the modal view controller appears. Then show your modal view controller(maybe rotate it first), hide it, and the parent controller should be just as before. I believe. Or maybe try playing with this kind of conbinations

Comment: You misunderstand. The parent view only allows one orientation. The modal view has a toggle button which allows you to choose which orientation. For example: the parent view is in portrait, you open the modal view and select landscape. The modal dismisses and the parent view goes to landscape orientation. This all works, but the animation is clunky and i'd like to get rid of it. I'd like the parent view to have already switched orientation when the modal view dismisses.