# How to pass a touch event from a UIView to the UIView(s) beneath it?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad

A simple problem but I can't find a solution for it:

I have 2 UIViews, one above the other in the same parent view. Both have `GestureRecognizers` on them but only the top most is receiving the events. How can I make the top most view pass all the gestures he gets to the other UIViews beneath it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is how i pass touches...

Subclass the uiview
and add

```
-(id)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UIView *hitView = [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
    if (hitView == self){
        return nil;
    }
    else {
        return hitView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -4):

It seems you need to use the NSNotificationCenter for the said task.
Have a look at this [tutorial](http://macdevelopertips.com/cocoa/basics-of-notifications.html).