# iOS - Rotate UINavigationController's top and bottom bar, but leave any pushed views intact

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, autorotate

I would like to auto-rotate the top and bottom bars of the navigation view controller when orientation changes, but leave everything else intact. As in - all the views pushed onto the navigation controller do not move one bit, but the top and bottom bars of the navigation controller show at the top and bottom of the new orientation.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reference this post's answer for information on only rotating parts of your view:

[iOS: Disable Autorotation for a Subview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7353789/ios-disable-autorotation-for-a-subview)

You should be able to put your top and bottom bars in a rotating viewcontroller, and separate the other views into a non-rotating one.

Hope that helps!