# Multiple orientation in a single viewcontroller, with UISplitview based application

Tags: ios, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller, device-orientation

I have an application which works only on Landscape mode, and the `rootViewController` of the application window is a `UISplitViewController`. Now, I want a new `viewController` to be presented as a modal view controller that support both orientations (landscape and portrait). I have set the supported orientations in plist as Landscape only. However I have set all orientations in the new view controller. But, the orientations in not changing to portrait, may be because of the orientations specified in the plist.

What I basically want, is to have all the views in the application in landscape mode and just a single view in both orientations. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation will tell the app to orient or not so what we can do here is have a flag which will tell to auto rotate or not. initially flag is false. but when you present a model view controller set it to true. and as it disappears set it to false again. this may do the trick
[you can also refer this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7353789/ios-disable-autorotation-for-a-subview)