# Prevent UIView from Rotation

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, rotation

i have two uiviews as containers on my mainview.
now i want to rotate the device. the content from container 1 should rotate together with the statusbar. 
the second container should stay as it is. 
at start the second container is like a footer toolbar but after rotation it should bi like a bar on the right/left.

how can i do this?

my viewcontroller allows to rotate and at the storyboard i have autoresize subviews activated.

at my app the footer bar will stay at the footer with full width of the screen. 
how can i fix the position of this view?

the result should look like the footer bar of the iphone springboard on the iPhone 6plus

Comment: Did you saw this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7353789/ios-disable-autorotation-for-a-subview If you build something simple go with the `UIWindow` based answer. Otherwise I suggest to use multiple view controllers.

Comment: i saw the question. it doesnt worked for me. the container will always be moved or resized and rotated.
with counter-rotation it doesnt helped because i will jump around :(

Comment: Ah, I see. The bar animation in iPhone 6+ is pretty interesting. The internal parts rotates but the outer layout remains same.

Comment: the statusbar should rotate full size. i think there is no way to change this behavior. But the rotation like the menubar on the bottom should be possible.