# How to show UIButtons present on the view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uibutton, uiwindow

I had a `UIViewController` on whose view I had started an `AVCaptureSession` and added two `UIButtons` to capture photos and close the camera,

I was facing the issue that the `AVCaptureSession` was also getting rotated when I was rotating the device,

To solve the problem I followed the second answer on this link,

```
<https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7353789/ios-disable-autorotation-for-a-subview>
```

But after adding on the window if I am making the view on the window of the full width and height as the self.view I am not being able to see the buttons

Any suggestions how I can bring the buttons visible while adding the window view as full width and height as the view of my view controller.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably have to create a subView of the "full width and height" view that you have created, and put the buttons over there (instead of in self.view).

Edit:
You might also try calling bringSubViewToFront on both buttons.