# Disable some of the animations during device orientation changes

Tags: ios, swift2, core-animation, calayer, quartz-core

Is there any way to disable rotation animation during changing device orientation portrait/landscape in only one UIView and its subviews.

Currently I'm using something like that from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4290050/disable-orientation-change-rotation-animation):

```
override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize,
      withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransitionToSize(size, withTransitionCoordinator: coordinator)
    CATransaction.begin()
    CATransaction.setDisableActions(true)

    coordinator.animateAlongsideTransition({ (ctx) -> Void in

    }, completion: { (ctx) -> Void in
      CATransaction.commit()
  })

}
```

But this solution disable all the animations during changing the orientation in every UIView on the screen.

I was trying also to create special NotAnimatedView subclass of UIView with no luck at all:

```
class NotAnimatedView: UIView {

  override func actionForLayer(layer: CALayer, forKey event: String) -> CAAction? {
    if event == "bounds" || event == "position" {
      return NSNull()
    }
    return super.actionForLayer(layer, forKey: event)
  }


}
```

The "bounds" and "position" was the two events that was occuring during changing the orientation of the device so I override them and return NSNull() according to [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/ReactingtoLayerChanges/ReactingtoLayerChanges.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004514-CH7-SW1)

But It's not working. The NotAnimatedView is also animating. It seems that I don understand something or my understanding of CALayer is wrong. Can somebody put more light on this topic?

Comment: A possible workaround could be to animate the "non-animating" view backwards. Calculate the frame of the view after rotation as if the view stayed on screen without moving, and animate it to that position in `animateAlongsideTransition`. So it will appear like it's not animating and is stuck on the screen.