# How to disable the device rotation animation in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, animation, swiftui, screen-rotation

For UIKit to disable the device rotation animation you could override the viewWillTransitionToSize method.
[Disable orientation change rotation animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4290050/disable-orientation-change-rotation-animation/6292506)
**But what would be the best way to achieve this in SwiftUI?**

Comment: did you find any solution to this issue? I'm having the same problem

Comment: Bump. Any news on this? Been looking for a solution for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this almost in the same way - create a helper view controller with animation blocker and use it inside background as representable.

Tested with Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5

```
struct HelperView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> some UIViewController {
        OrientationHandler()
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewControllerType, context: Context) {
    }

    class OrientationHandler: UIViewController {
        override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
            coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: nil) { _ in
                UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)
            }
            UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)
            super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator);
        }
    }
}
```

and usage:

```
    WindowGroup {
        ContentView()
          .background(HelperView())   // << here !!
    }
```

[Module on GitHub](https://github.com/Asperi-Demo/4SwiftUI/blob/master/PlayOn_iOS/PlayOn_iOS/Helpers/Representables.swift)