# How to turn off screen rotation animation while switching from landscape to portrait and vice versa

Tags: flutter, user-interface, orientation

In app during some transitions between screens (from app mode with veritical lock to game mode with horizontal lock ) I use

```
await SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
  DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
  DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
]);
```

to switch users between screen orientations, but sometimes this animation looks laggy on low-to-mid-end devices

**Is it possible in flutter to skip or for example speed up screen rotation animation?**

Or maybe someone know workaround without using setPreferredOrientations

Comment: What about showing a `CircularProgressIndicator` while the animation is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is that, static lock the app's screen orientation ,

then detect screen orientation changes,

finally, DIY your screen rotation logics.

*no animation is also OK.*

- Firstly, do as @dengST30's answer

and simple `SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations` is sufficient

- Secondly, detect screen orientation changes

in iOS, native code again:

**register notification:**

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(AppDelegate.rotated), name: UIDevice.orientationDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
```

**rotation detected:**

```
@objc func rotated() {
    if UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape {
         print("Landscape")
    }
    else if UIDevice.current.orientation.isPortrait {
         print("Portrait")
    }
}
```

- **thirdly, you can skip or speed up screen rotation animation, now**

write your own animation and UI transform code now.

Answer (score 1):

for `using setPreferredOrientations` while Flutter app in iOS devices

[image: 111]

---

as I tested, for `using setPreferredOrientations` while Flutter app in Android devices, there is no device rotation

Comment: Thank you for your answer, you got that I was asking about animation during orientation change, right?

Comment: for: Or maybe someone know workaround without using setPreferredOrientations

Comment: not very  possible in flutter to skip or for example speed up screen rotation animation

Comment: as I know , Flutter app in iOS side is FlutterViewController. So rotation is the native thing.

Comment: ok I got your point - then how do you change in-app orientation with this aproach?

Comment: Open iOS project workplace with Xcode, then do as the page. If you own the app.

Answer (score 1):

To lock the screen orientation to landscape on both iOS and Android do the following. This would make the app start in landscape mode from the beginning.

### iOS - Info.plist

Locate the file `ios/Runner/Info.plist` and change/add the `UISupportedInterfaceOrientations` key (or `UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad` key for iPadOS) like so ([Docs reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW10)).

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>

    <!-- ... removed initial keys for clarity ... -->

    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

### Android - AndroidManifest.xml

Locate the file `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` and change/add the `activity` attribute `android:screenOrientation="landscape"` ([Docs reference](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#screen)).

```xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.example">
   <application
        android:label="Example"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            ...
        >

            <!-- ... removed this section for clarity ... -->

        </activity>
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: I've interpreted the question `How to turn off screen rotation animation while switching from landscape to portrait and vice versa` this way. It looks like it's a bit ambiguous as `animation` in this context could be just the consequence of rotating or the exact thing you're trying to disable. I.e. `How to turn off the rotation?` or `How to turn off the rotation's animation?`. Anyway, I think it's not possible to disable the animation _per se_ as it's native to the OS. Good luck!

Comment: Anything in flutter is native to OS one way or another :) Thank you anyway

Comment: Do you need this for both `Android` and `iOS`?

Comment: mainly yes, I understand the state of flutter web for now, so no biggie if it is only mobile oriented solution, why you ask?

Comment: I was looking for a solution to this for a long time and tbh had no expectation someone  will help. I was interested if someone could explain at least why this is not possible

Comment: It's actually possible if you create a native plugin for `Android` and/or `iOS`.  Take a look on [this question for iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4290050/disable-orientation-change-rotation-animation) and [this other one for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21165739/2828341)

Comment: yep, I saw that articles, thats why was asking if that was a thing for flutter, looks like I would really had to write a package on this feature myself